# Joint 2 Tables Together in CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

Hey guys i have 2 tables, `items` and `item_translations` where item has fields

**id | address | status | created | modified | is_active**

and item_translations has fields

**id | item_id | item_name | item_description | language_code**

so it is a multilingual website.

So relations are

`items` hasMany `item_translations`

`item_translations` belongsTo `Item`.

So what i want to do is that when user select a language based on the language he returns to return specific row of translation for each property.

for example item with (1)  is translated in 3 language it, en, de when user selects en it returns items with id=x and item_translations with item_id=x and language_code=en, but it should return only one row of hasMany relation.

So my query so far is:

```
$this->Paginator->settings =  array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'item_translations',
            'alias' => 'ItemTranslation',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Item.id = ItemTranslation.item_id')
        )
    ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Item.item_status'=>1, 
            'User.is_actve'=>1,
            'ItemTranslation.language_code' => $language_code
        ),
        'limit' => 5,
        'order' => array('Item.sort' => 'ASC'),
        'recursive' => 1
);
$items = $this->paginate('Item');
```

But the problem with this is that it returns this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Item] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                    [address] => Località Montecalvo di Sotto, 63, 02038 Scandriglia RI, Italy
                    [created] => 2015-03-09 17:13:53
                    [modified] => 2015-03-09 17:13:53
                    [is_active] => 
                    ---------
                )
            [ItemTranslation] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (   
                            [id] => 78
                            [item_id] => 17
                            [language_code] => en
                            [item_name] => This is the title of this property in ventita
                            [item_description] => This is a module for tradure in other language diponibile
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 79
                            [item_id] => 17
                            [language_code] => de
                            [item_name] => Dies ist der Titel dieser Eigenschaft in Ventita
                            [item_description] => Dies ist ein Modul zum tradure in anderen Sprach diponibile

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 80
                            [item_id] => 17
                            [language_code] => 
                            [item_name] => Questo e il titolo da questo proprieta in ventita
                            [item_description] => Questo e una module per tradure in altre lingua diponibile
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Instead of returning only one row where language_code=en or de it returns all translations related to this item.

Please any help i would really appreciate it..
Thanx in advance

Comment: Instead of `JOIN`'s, use the [containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html), focus on [deeper associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations) - the example mimics your requirement

Comment: @AgRizzo Thanx for your answer, but id ask another thing, a stupid question really, how you would do it  in my case bbecause it doesent seem to work to me??

Comment: Why doesn't it work (you need to be specific)? Wouldn't your solution include something like `array('contain' => 'ItemTranslation.language_code = $language_code')`?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the language_code to the condition in your Joins array should do it:

```
$this->Paginator->settings =  array(
'joins' => array(
    array(
        'table' => 'item_translations',
        'alias' => 'ItemTranslation',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Item.id = ItemTranslation.item_id',
            'ItemTranslation.language_code' => $language_code
        )
    )
),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Item.item_status'=>1, 
        'User.is_actve'=>1
    ),
    'limit' => 5,
    'order' => array('Item.sort' => 'ASC'),
    'recursive' => 1
);
$items = $this->paginate('Item');
```

In general though you will probably have an easier time with translations if you use Cake's Translate behaviour - a lot of the heavy lifting is already done for you:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html